# WiFi frequently disconnects on Ubuntu 16.04 and is not working in 14.04

Tags: networking, dual-boot, wireless, 16.04, uefi

I have an hp 15-ac110tx and dual booted with Ubuntu and Windows 10 in UEFI mode with secure boot off. All the things are latest updated and upgraded. But WiFi frequently disconnects.

The output of this command:

> wget -N -t 5 -T 10 https://github.com/UbuntuForums/wireless-info/raw/master/wireless-info && \
>   chmod +x wireless-info && \
>   ./wireless-info

is as follows:

```
           ########## wireless info START ##########

           Report from: 11 Jul 2016 23:02 IST +0530

           Booted last: 11 Jul 2016 00:00 IST +0530

           Script from: 08 Jul 2016 02:16 UTC +0000

           ##### release ###########################

           Distributor ID:  Ubuntu
           Description: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
           Release: 16.04
           Codename:    xenial

           ##### kernel ############################

           Linux 4.4.0-28-generic #47-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jun 24 10:09:13 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

           Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=7

           ##### desktop ###########################

           Ubuntu

           ##### lspci #############################

           07:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller [10ec:8136] (rev 07)
            Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller [103c:80c2]
            Kernel driver in use: r8169

           13:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:b723]
            Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [103c:804c]
            Kernel driver in use: rtl8723be

           ##### lsusb #############################

           Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
           Bus 001 Device 003: ID 05c8:0382 Cheng Uei Precision Industry Co., Ltd (Foxlink) 
           Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0bda:b006 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
           Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

           ##### PCMCIA card info ##################

           ##### rfkill ############################

           0: hci0: Bluetooth
            Soft blocked: no
            Hard blocked: no
           1: phy0: Wireless LAN
            Soft blocked: no
            Hard blocked: no

           ##### lsmod #############################

           hp_wmi                 16384  0
           sparse_keymap          16384  1 hp_wmi
           rtl8723be             135168  0
           btcoexist             180224  1 rtl8723be
           rtl_pci                40960  1 rtl8723be
           rtlwifi               102400  3 btcoexist,rtl_pci,rtl8723be
           mac80211              737280  3 rtl_pci,rtlwifi,rtl8723be
           snd_soc_rt286          36864  0
           cfg80211              565248  2 mac80211,rtlwifi
           snd_soc_rl6347a        16384  1 snd_soc_rt286
           snd_soc_core          212992  2 snd_soc_ssm4567,snd_soc_rt286
           snd_pcm               106496  7 snd_soc_core,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_soc_rt286,snd_pcm_dmaengine,snd_hda_core
           wmi                    20480  1 hp_wmi

           ##### interfaces ########################

           auto lo
           iface lo inet loopback

           ##### ifconfig ##########################

           enp7s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'enp7s0' [IF1]>  
                     UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
                     RX packets:68 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
                     TX packets:126 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
                     collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
                     RX bytes:9462 (9.4 KB)  TX bytes:13253 (13.2 KB)

           wlp19s0   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'wlp19s0' [IF2]>  
                     inet addr:192.168.1.6  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
                     inet6 addr: fe80::bc71:687e:d996:1657/64 Scope:Link
                     UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
                     RX packets:3882 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
                     TX packets:4075 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
                     collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
                     RX bytes:2712625 (2.7 MB)  TX bytes:1000401 (1.0 MB)

           ##### iwconfig ##########################

           enp7s0    no wireless extensions.

           lo        no wireless extensions.

           wlp19s0   IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:"BRIJ RAJ"  
                     Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.462 GHz  Access Point: <MAC 'BRIJ RAJ' [AC1]>   
                     Bit Rate=72.2 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
                     Retry short limit:7   RTS thr=2347 B   Fragment thr:off
                     Power Management:off
                     Link Quality=48/70  Signal level=-62 dBm  
                     Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
                     Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:1584   Missed beacon:0

           ##### route #############################

           Kernel IP routing table
           Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
           0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    600    0        0 wlp19s0
           169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 wlp19s0
           192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     600    0        0 wlp19s0

           ##### resolv.conf #######################

           nameserver 127.0.1.1
           search domain.name

           ##### network managers ##################

           Installed:

            NetworkManager

           Running:

           root       747     1  0 22:56 ?        00:00:01 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon

           ##### NetworkManager info ###############

           GENERAL.DEVICE:                         wlp19s0
           GENERAL.TYPE:                           wifi
           GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceWifi
           GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
           GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
           GENERAL.DRIVER:                         rtl8723be
           GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 4.4.0-28-generic
           GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               N/A
           GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'wlp19s0' [IF2]>
           GENERAL.MTU:                            0
           GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
           GENERAL.REASON:                         0 (No reason given)
           GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.5/0000:13:00.0/net/wlp19s0
           GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       wlp19s0
           GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
           GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
           GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
           GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
           GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
           GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
           GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     BRIJ RAJ
           GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       ea93de0a-5e76-4bb1-b2b8-68451675dc58
           GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/1
           GENERAL.METERED:                        no (guessed)
           CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            no
           CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     72 Mb/s
           CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
           WIFI-PROPERTIES.WEP:                    yes
           WIFI-PROPERTIES.WPA:                    yes
           WIFI-PROPERTIES.WPA2:                   yes
           WIFI-PROPERTIES.TKIP:                   yes
           WIFI-PROPERTIES.CCMP:                   yes
           WIFI-PROPERTIES.AP:                     yes
           WIFI-PROPERTIES.ADHOC:                  yes
           WIFI-PROPERTIES.2GHZ:                   yes
           WIFI-PROPERTIES.5GHZ:                   no
           CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/{0}
           CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[1]:   ea93de0a-5e76-4bb1-b2b8-68451675dc58 | BRIJ RAJ
           IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         192.168.1.6/24
           IP4.GATEWAY:                            192.168.1.1
           IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 169.254.0.0/16, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 1000
           IP4.DNS[1]:                             202.56.215.54
           IP4.DNS[2]:                             202.56.215.55
           IP4.DOMAIN[1]:                          domain.name
           DHCP4.OPTION[1]:                        requested_routers = 1
           DHCP4.OPTION[2]:                        requested_domain_search = 1
           DHCP4.OPTION[3]:                        requested_time_offset = 1
           DHCP4.OPTION[4]:                        requested_domain_name = 1
           DHCP4.OPTION[5]:                        requested_rfc3442_classless_static_routes = 1
           DHCP4.OPTION[6]:                        requested_broadcast_address = 1
           DHCP4.OPTION[7]:                        requested_netbios_scope = 1
           DHCP4.OPTION[8]:                        requested_wpad = 1
           DHCP4.OPTION[9]:                        next_server = 0.0.0.0
           DHCP4.OPTION[10]:                       expiry = 1468517198
           DHCP4.OPTION[11]:                       requested_interface_mtu = 1
           DHCP4.OPTION[12]:                       requested_subnet_mask = 1
           DHCP4.OPTION[13]:                       routers = 192.168.1.1
           DHCP4.OPTION[14]:                       dhcp_message_type = 5
           DHCP4.OPTION[15]:                       ip_address = 192.168.1.6
           DHCP4.OPTION[16]:                       requested_static_routes = 1
           DHCP4.OPTION[17]:                       domain_name = domain.name
           DHCP4.OPTION[18]:                       requested_domain_name_servers = 1
           DHCP4.OPTION[19]:                       broadcast_address = 192.168.1.255
           DHCP4.OPTION[20]:                       requested_ntp_servers = 1
           DHCP4.OPTION[21]:                       requested_netbios_name_servers = 1
           DHCP4.OPTION[22]:                       dhcp_lease_time = 259200
           DHCP4.OPTION[23]:                       domain_name_servers = 202.56.215.54 202.56.215.55
           DHCP4.OPTION[24]:                       requested_ms_classless_static_routes = 1
           DHCP4.OPTION[25]:                       subnet_mask = 255.255.255.0
           DHCP4.OPTION[26]:                       network_number = 192.168.1.0
           DHCP4.OPTION[27]:                       requested_host_name = 1
           DHCP4.OPTION[28]:                       dhcp_server_identifier = 192.168.1.1
           IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         fe80::bc71:687e:d996:1657/64
           IP6.GATEWAY:                            fe80::bac1:a2ff:fe15:1234
           IP6.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = fe80::bac1:a2ff:fe15:1234/128, nh = ::, mt = 600

           GENERAL.DEVICE:                         enp7s0
           GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
           GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceEthernet
           GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
           GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller
           GENERAL.DRIVER:                         r8169
           GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 2.3LK-NAPI
           GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               
           GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'enp7s0' [IF1]>
           GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
           GENERAL.STATE:                          20 (unavailable)
           GENERAL.REASON:                         40 (Carrier/link changed)
           GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.2/0000:07:00.0/net/enp7s0
           GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       
           GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
           GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
           GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
           GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
           GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
           GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
           GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
           GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       --
           GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --
           GENERAL.METERED:                        unknown
           CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            yes
           CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     100 Mb/s
           CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
           WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               off
           CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: 

           SSID      BSSID              MODE   CHAN  FREQ      RATE       SIGNAL  BARS  SECURITY  ACTIVE  * 
           BRIJ RAJ  <MAC 'BRIJ RAJ' [AC1]>  Infra  11    2462 MHz  54 Mbit/s  54      ▂▄__  WPA2      yes     * 
           MGMNT     <MAC 'MGMNT' [AC2]>  Infra  11    2462 MHz  54 Mbit/s  50      ▂▄__  WEP       no        

           ##### NetworkManager.state ##############

           [main]
           NetworkingEnabled=true
           WirelessEnabled=true
           WWANEnabled=true

           ##### NetworkManager.conf ###############

           [main]
           plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
           dns=dnsmasq

           [ifupdown]
           managed=false

           ##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

           [[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/BRIJ RAJ]] (600 root)
           [connection] id=BRIJ RAJ | type=wifi | permissions=user:gaurav:;
           [wifi] mac-address=<MAC 'wlp19s0' [IF2]> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=BRIJ RAJ
           [ipv4] method=auto
           [ipv6] method=auto

           ##### iw reg get ########################

           Region: Asia/Kolkata (based on set time zone)

           country 00: DFS-UNSET
            (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (N/A, 20), (N/A)
            (2457 - 2482 @ 40), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-IR
            (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-OFDM, NO-IR
            (5170 - 5250 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-IR
            (5250 - 5330 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, NO-IR
            (5490 - 5730 @ 160), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, NO-IR
            (5735 - 5835 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-IR
            (57240 - 63720 @ 2160), (N/A, 0), (N/A)

           ##### iwlist channels ###################

           enp7s0    no frequency information.

           lo        no frequency information.

           wlp19s0   13 channels in total; available frequencies :
                     Channel 01 : 2.412 GHz
                     Channel 02 : 2.417 GHz
                     Channel 03 : 2.422 GHz
                     Channel 04 : 2.427 GHz
                     Channel 05 : 2.432 GHz
                     Channel 06 : 2.437 GHz
                     Channel 07 : 2.442 GHz
                     Channel 08 : 2.447 GHz
                     Channel 09 : 2.452 GHz
                     Channel 10 : 2.457 GHz
                     Channel 11 : 2.462 GHz
                     Channel 12 : 2.467 GHz
                     Channel 13 : 2.472 GHz
                     Current Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)

           ##### iwlist scan #######################

           enp7s0    Interface doesn't support scanning.

           lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

           Channel occupancy:

                 2   APs on   Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)

           wlp19s0   Scan completed :
                     Cell 01 - Address: <MAC 'BRIJ RAJ' [AC1]>
                               Channel:11
                               Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)
                               Quality=46/70  Signal level=-64 dBm  
                               Encryption key:on
                               ESSID:"BRIJ RAJ"
                               Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s
                                         9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                               Bit Rates:24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                               Mode:Master
                               Extra:tsf=0000000757aa63bb
                               Extra: Last beacon: 32ms ago
                               IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                                   Group Cipher : TKIP
                                   Pairwise Ciphers (2) : TKIP CCMP
                                   Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                     Cell 02 - Address: <MAC 'MGMNT' [AC2]>
                               Channel:11
                               Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)
                               Quality=48/70  Signal level=-62 dBm  
                               Encryption key:on
                               ESSID:"MGMNT"
                               Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s
                                         9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                               Bit Rates:24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                               Mode:Master
                               Extra:tsf=0000000757aa6e31
                               Extra: Last beacon: 24ms ago

           ##### module infos ######################

           [rtl8723be]
           filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.0-28-generic/updates/dkms/rtl8723be.ko
           firmware:       rtlwifi/rtl8723befw.bin
           description:    Realtek 8723BE 802.11n PCI wireless
           license:        GPL
           author:         Realtek WlanFAE  <wlanfae@realtek.com>
           author:         PageHe   <page_he@realsil.com.cn>
           srcversion:     00619764255210776FAB54D
           depends:        rtlwifi,rtl_pci,btcoexist,mac80211
           vermagic:       4.4.0-28-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
           parm:           swlps:bool
           parm:           swenc:using hardware crypto (default 0 [hardware])
            (bool)
           parm:           ips:using no link power save (default 1 is open)
            (bool)
           parm:           fwlps:using linked fw control power save (default 1 is open)
            (bool)
           parm:           msi:Set to 1 to use MSI interrupts mode (default 0)
            (bool)
           parm:           debug:Set debug level (0-5) (default 0) (int)
           parm:           disable_watchdog:Set to 1 to disable the watchdog (default 0)
            (bool)
           parm:           ant_sel:Set to 1 or 2 to force antenna number (default 0)
            (int)

           [rtl_pci]
           filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.0-28-generic/updates/dkms/rtl_pci.ko
           description:    PCI basic driver for rtlwifi
           license:        GPL
           author:         Larry Finger <Larry.FInger@lwfinger.net>
           author:         Realtek WlanFAE  <wlanfae@realtek.com>
           author:         lizhaoming   <chaoming_li@realsil.com.cn>
           srcversion:     8552A7BAFD0FCC2C41CF075
           depends:        mac80211,rtlwifi
           vermagic:       4.4.0-28-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 

           [rtlwifi]
           filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.0-28-generic/updates/dkms/rtlwifi.ko
           description:    Realtek 802.11n PCI wireless core
           license:        GPL
           author:         Larry Finger <Larry.FInger@lwfinger.net>
           author:         Realtek WlanFAE  <wlanfae@realtek.com>
           author:         lizhaoming   <chaoming_li@realsil.com.cn>
           srcversion:     990116D31097F1C4C1F7006
           depends:        mac80211,cfg80211
           vermagic:       4.4.0-28-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 

           [mac80211]
           filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.0-28-generic/kernel/net/mac80211/mac80211.ko
           license:        GPL
           description:    IEEE 802.11 subsystem
           srcversion:     2FFAEED0245CA1D97FE1E44
           depends:        cfg80211
           intree:         Y
           vermagic:       4.4.0-28-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
           parm:           minstrel_vht_only:Use only VHT rates when VHT is supported by sta. (bool)
           parm:           max_nullfunc_tries:Maximum nullfunc tx tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
           parm:           max_probe_tries:Maximum probe tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
           parm:           beacon_loss_count:Number of beacon intervals before we decide beacon was lost. (int)
           parm:           probe_wait_ms:Maximum time(ms) to wait for probe response before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
           parm:           ieee80211_default_rc_algo:Default rate control algorithm for mac80211 to use (charp)

           [cfg80211]
           filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.0-28-generic/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
           description:    wireless configuration support
           license:        GPL
           author:         Johannes Berg
           srcversion:     25A45701AAA64DAC1E47D9D
           depends:        
           intree:         Y
           vermagic:       4.4.0-28-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
           parm:           ieee80211_regdom:IEEE 802.11 regulatory domain code (charp)
           parm:           cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz:Disable 40MHz support in the 2.4GHz band (bool)

           ##### module parameters #################

           [rtl8723be]
           ant_sel: 0
           debug: 1
           disable_watchdog: N
           fwlps: Y
           ips: Y
           msi: N
           swenc: N
           swlps: N

           [mac80211]
           beacon_loss_count: 7
           ieee80211_default_rc_algo: minstrel_ht
           max_nullfunc_tries: 2
           max_probe_tries: 5
           minstrel_vht_only: Y
           probe_wait_ms: 500

           [cfg80211]
           cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz: N
           ieee80211_regdom: 00

           ##### /etc/modules ######################

           ##### modprobe options ##################

           [/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
           blacklist ath_pci

           [/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
           blacklist evbug
           blacklist usbmouse
           blacklist usbkbd
           blacklist eepro100
           blacklist de4x5
           blacklist eth1394
           blacklist snd_intel8x0m
           blacklist snd_aw2
           blacklist i2c_i801
           blacklist prism54
           blacklist bcm43xx
           blacklist garmin_gps
           blacklist asus_acpi
           blacklist snd_pcsp
           blacklist pcspkr
           blacklist amd76x_edac

           [/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
           alias net-pf-3 off
           alias net-pf-6 off
           alias net-pf-9 off
           alias net-pf-11 off
           alias net-pf-12 off
           alias net-pf-19 off
           alias net-pf-21 off
           alias net-pf-36 off

           [/etc/modprobe.d/intel-microcode-blacklist.conf]
           blacklist microcode

           [/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
           remove iwlwifi \
           (/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
           && /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

           [/etc/modprobe.d/mlx4.conf]
           softdep mlx4_core post: mlx4_en

           ##### rc.local ##########################

           exit 0

           ##### pm-utils ##########################

           ##### udev rules ########################

           ##### dmesg #############################

           [   11.650862] Bluetooth: hci0: rtl: examining hci_ver=06 hci_rev=000b lmp_ver=06 lmp_subver=8723
           [   11.650864] Bluetooth: hci0: rtl: loading rtl_bt/rtl8723b_fw.bin
           [   11.896271] Using firmware rtlwifi/rtl8723befw.bin
           [   11.896436] rtlwifi: channel plan 0x20
           [   11.896438] rtlwifi: country code 11
           [   11.944824] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'rtl_rc'
           [   11.945051] rtlwifi: wireless switch is on
           [   12.407322] rtl8723be 0000:13:00.0 wlp19s0: renamed from wlan0
           [   33.309909] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp7s0: link is not ready
           [   33.534976] r8169 0000:07:00.0 enp7s0: link down (repeated 2 times)
           [   33.535030] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp7s0: link is not ready
           [   33.571460] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp19s0: link is not ready
           [   35.083684] r8169 0000:07:00.0 enp7s0: link up
           [   35.164545] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp19s0: link is not ready
           [   35.165249] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): enp7s0: link becomes ready
           [   36.495891] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp19s0: link is not ready
           [   61.292087] wlp19s0: authenticate with <MAC 'BRIJ RAJ' [AC1]>
           [   61.314753] wlp19s0: send auth to <MAC 'BRIJ RAJ' [AC1]> (try 1/3)
           [   61.323221] wlp19s0: authenticated
           [   61.327475] wlp19s0: associate with <MAC 'BRIJ RAJ' [AC1]> (try 1/3)
           [   61.334621] wlp19s0: RX AssocResp from <MAC 'BRIJ RAJ' [AC1]> (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=12)
           [   61.335012] wlp19s0: associated
           [   61.335019] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp19s0: link becomes ready
           [   94.522788] r8169 0000:07:00.0 enp7s0: link down

           ########## wireless info END ############
```

Comment: The above notwithstanding, you should also change the wireless encryption settings to WPA2-AES, not any WPA/WPA2 mixed mode and certainly not TKIP.